# Как добавить удаление новости в php файле.

Tags: php

Привет, всем. Скажите вот я сделал по видео-уроку файл с добавлением новостей, но вот беда... в нём не рассказали как её удалить(без phpmyadmin). Вот сам код, что получился.

```
    <hr>
<html>
<center><h1>Новости</h1></center>
<hr>
<?php
if ($_POST['post'])
{

$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['body'];
if($title&&$body)
{
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "159357") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("admin") or die(mysql_error());
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news VALUES('','$title','$body','$date')") or die(mysql_error());
die("Новость добавлена");
}
else
echo "Заполните все поля<p>";
}

?>
<center><form action = 'post.php' method = 'POST'>
Название : <br>
<input type ='text' name='title'><p>
Текст : <br>
<textarea rows='6' cols='35' name='body'></textarea><p>
<input type='submit' name='post' value='Добавить новость'>
</form></center>
</hr>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут как бы зависит от запроса, например так:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM news WHERE id='" .news_id. "'");
```

Вот и копайте в эту сторону :) И еще, что это за ужасная строчка:

```
die("Новость добавлена");
```

Где вы такое вычитали вообще? :)

Comment: ахаха!!!! 

die("Новость добавлена");

Comment: [http://hashcode.ru/users/5119/shamanis][1] спасибо, поднял настроение)


  [1]: http://@Shamanis

Comment: if($title&&$body){
        ...
        die("Новость добавлена");
    }
    else echo "Заполните все поля<p>";

На ГК, однозначно).

Comment: Ребят, если он это в видео-уроке увидел, то мне реально страшно становится О_о

Comment: Он Попова небось смотрел, только попов может такое выдать в своих видео уроках :D

Comment: Ну вот то почему я делал ....

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm_VNqF6i7o
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdF3IboO0Cw&feature=relmfu
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEpgs8SG58g&feature=relmfu

Comment: А какой там голос! Жесть, а не проще было где-нибудь скачать готовое?
И CRUD есть такая штука. 
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD

Comment: @Angus123, и тебе хоть что-то понятно в тех видео уроках? Я бы не советовал это смотреть

Comment: вот, посмотри лучше это

http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3692373

http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3692393

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но, мне не надо учить php, мне надо только узнать как добавить кнопку "Удалить новость", и она будет удалять новость которая будет в списке ниже...

Comment: @Angus123, если вы не знаете php, вам даже сложно будет объяснить как это сделать, хотя, объяснить будет легко, но вы ничего не поймете. А писать код за вас никто не будет, а если и будет, все-равно предоставлено мало информации. Вам уже дали подсказку в этом ответе, гуглите. Или скачайте готовый скрипт новостей и не заставляйте кипеть ваше серое вещество.

Comment: 300 деревянных и я "бесплатно" тебе напишу код, раз ты не хочешь изучать PHP, а свои мысли я бесплатно тебе не да :P

Comment: @Shrek злодей ))

Comment: Да :), а то как жить то на одну зп :)